# How to slide up the div clicking anywhere on page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I have a div. which I make slide up and slide down by jquery function myjquery function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function () {

        $("#nav > li > a").click(function () { // binding onclick
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
                $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(700); // hiding popups
                $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
            } else {
                $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(400); // hiding popups
                $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");

                if ($(this).next(".subs").length) {
                    $(this).parent().addClass("selected"); // display popup
                    $(this).next(".subs").children().slideDown(200);
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

and html is

```
<ul id="nav">    
            <li><a href="#"><b>Login</b></a>
                <div class="subs">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <table style="margin-right:12PX;width:200px;overflow:scroll;">
                            <tr style="width:70px"><td>Mobile Number</td></tr>
                           <tr> <td><asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="TextBox1" CssClass="selectfield" Width="170px"/></td>
                            </tr><tr><td>Password</td></tr><tr><td><asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" TextMode="Password" Width="170px" CssClass="selectfield"  /></td></tr>
                            <tr style="height:5px;"><td></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>
                                &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" 
                                    runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="btn" onclick="Button1_Click"  /></td></tr>
                                <tr><td style="color:Red;">
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="link">Forget Password</asp:LinkButton></td></tr>
                            </table>
                            </ul>
```

when I click on login the div sub is slide down and again clicking on login the div slideup. it run perfectly. I want when I click on login div should slide down. after than if click anywhere on the page except `<div>`. The `<div>` should slideup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WxcLV/10/
Instead of `click` try it using `mouseup` as below:

```
$('#loginButton').mouseup(function(login) {
    $('#loginBox').toggle();
    $('#loginButton').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#loginTable').mouseup(function() { 
    // to avoid hiding div 
    return false;
});
$(this).mouseup(function(login) {
    if(!($(login.target).parent('#loginButton').length > 0)) {
        $('#loginButton').removeClass('active');
        $('#loginBox').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: prasad i try it but it is not working, div slide up and down when i click on login

Comment: I do it by changing the name of target div it works but not always hw to improve it so that it works alyways when i click on login

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
$(document).bind("click", function (event) {      
    if (!$(event.target).is('.subs') && $(event.target).closest('.subs').length==0) {
        $("#nav .selected div div").slideUp(700);
        $("#nav .selected").removeClass("selected");
    }
});
```

you also need to take care if you clicked inside div.

Comment: as you saw my html I am using div for login I have to click inside the div is there any method I click inside div nothing happens.otherwise it's working fine

Comment: what do you want then ? the above code will hide your div when clicking anywhere on the document except the div itself

Comment: when i click inside the div the div is hide i don't want this

Comment: It won't hide the div if you click in div having class name subs

Comment: I do it by changing '.sub' to "#nav > li > a" (check my html). thats the reason i am getting this. because with '.sub' class div is sliding up and down automatically

Answer (score 0):

well i have a way around for it, Hope that it will work for you, Please take a Container div or lets take the body tag(which size is such that it cover's the entire page e.g, 100%,)and add it an onclick event and in that event slide up the div.Take Care of the fact that your Container div or the Body tag should cover the entire page so that it look's like that the user is clicking any where on the page. that is the trick

let me know if it helps or not.